# SwiftUI @FocusState not working in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This code works great, just as it should. isFocused reflects the focus state of the text field, and pressing the Button drops the keyboard.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textInput = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter text", text: $textInput)
                .focused($isFocused)
            
            Button("Submit") {
                isFocused = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, putting the TextField instead a ScrollView results in @FocusState NOT working. When the button is tapped, "Dismiss" is printed but the keyboard does not resign.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textInput = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            TextField("Enter text", text: $textInput)
                .focused($isFocused)
            Button("Dismiss") {
                isFocused = false
                print("Dismiss")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this the case? And how could this be fixed?

Comment: The code works for me. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Does it really? That's so strange. I just created a new Project and pasted this code in, and it doesn't work for me—the keyboard does not dismiss. Albeit I'm using XCode 15 beta & IOS 17 beta, but that shouldn't make a difference here.

Comment: I'm on Xcode 14.3 and iOS 16.4. Might be a SwiftUI bug in the beta perhaps.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the exact same problem on Xcode 15 beta 4, the same code works just fine in Xcode 14. Filed a bug report and hopefully it gets resolved in future versions.

Comment: Can you provide a link on bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same still with Xcode 15 beta 6.

A temporary workaround (though not ideal) is to replace your ScrollView with a VStack inside a List with listStyle set to plain, row separators set to hidden and row insets as (0, 0, 0, 0).

i.e.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textInput = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter text", text: $textInput)
                    .focused($isFocused)
                Button("Dismiss") {
                    isFocused = false
                    print("Dismiss")
                }
            }
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

This should produce identical results to a ScrollView. To avoid repeating the workaround pattern, here's a quick backporting wrapper.

```
struct BackportScrollView<Content: View>: View {
    var content: () -> Content
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) { self.content = content }
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            List {
                VStack { content() }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        } else {
            ScrollView(.vertical) { content() }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textInput = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        BackportScrollView {
            TextField("Enter text", text: $textInput)
                .focused($isFocused)
            Button("Dismiss") {
                isFocused = false
                print("Dismiss")
            }
        }
    }
}
```